# Checking if authenticated in ApplicationController resulting in "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Right now I'm unable to navigate to my Devise-created route `/users/edit` without getting the following error:

```
  ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:15:in `authenticate_user!'
  devise (4.3.0) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:133:in `authenticate_scope!'
  activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Callbacks>'
  activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:179:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `block in invoke_before'
  activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `each'
  activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:507:in `invoke_before'
  activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:130:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
  activerecord (5.1.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
  actionview (5.1.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:16:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:46:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:832:in `call'
  warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
  activerecord (5.1.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
  web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
  web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
  railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
  railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
  railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
  sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
  activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
  rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
  railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
  puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
  puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
  puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
  puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

The method causing the error is `ApplicationController:authenticate_user!` where I check to see if a user is authenticated before letting them go to any page. I also have a `before_action` call on all my controllers to this method.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  include Pundit

  layout :layout_by_resource

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name])
  end

  #####################################
  # This is what's giving me my error #
  #####################################
  def authenticate_user!
    unless signed_in?
      redirect_to login_path # halts request cycle
    end
  end

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller? && resource_name == :user && action_name == 'new'
      "empty_application"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end

end
```

What I'm wondering is why my `/users/edit` page specifically is giving me this problem when no other page is.

My routes look like the following:

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
                    root GET    /                              visitors#index
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
           user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
       user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                         POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
              home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)          home#index
              home_minor GET    /home/minor(.:format)          home#minor
                         GET    /                              home#index
                   login GET    /sign-in(.:format)             devise/sessions#new
                    page GET    /pages/*id                     high_voltage/pages#show
```

My **UsersController.rb** looks like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @users = User.all
    authorize User
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize @user
    if @user.update_attributes(secure_params)
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    authorize user
    user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
  end

  private

  def secure_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:role)
  end

end
```

And my **config/routes.rb** look like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'visitors#index'
  devise_for :users


  get "home/index"
  get "home/minor"
  root to: 'home#index'


  devise_scope :user do
    get '/sign-in' => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :login
  end

end
```

What am I doing in my `ApplicationController.authenticate_user!` method that's not allowing me to navigate to my `/users/edit` route and giving me the error, `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`?

Comment: Can you, please, provide the stacktrace for the error?

Comment: @IgorDrozdov Just added the stacktrace. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `authenticate_user!` takes one argument in it's [default implementation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb) (`authenticate_#{mapping}` method)

Thus, if you're going to override it, the definition should be the same:

```
def authenticate_user!(opts = {})
```

That's because somewhere the method may be called with an argument

By the way, I don't think you need to override it, because it's already implemented and does [what you expect it to do](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FControllers%2FHelpers.define_helpers)

Comment: That was totally it. I didn't realize that authenticate_user! does exactly what I was expecting. 

Thank you for your help.